# Find the limit of g(x,y) as (x,y) approaches (0,0) along these paths

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $\ \ \text{E}{\scriptstyle{\text{XERCISE}}}\ 8.$ Consider the function $$\begin{align}g:\ \mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(x,y)\mid x+y=0\}\ &\to\ \ \mathbb{R} \\ (x,y)\qquad\qquad\ \ &\mapsto\ \ \tfrac{\sin(x)}{x+y}\end{align}$$ Find the limit of $g(x,y)$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along the path
>   $(\text{a}) $ the $x$-axis,
>   $(\text{b}) $ the line $y=x$.
>   What do you deduce about $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}g(x,y)$?

I have been told by someone that my solution is incorrect. If someone could please clarify where I have gone wrong and post up their own solution for comparison, I would greatly appreciate it.

A) Approaching $(0,0)$ through the x-axis:

$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x,0)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x+y} = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

$\lim \limits_{(x) \to (0)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \frac{0}{0}$ Indeterminate form

B) Approaching $(0,0)$ through the line $y = x$:

$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (x,x)} \frac{\sin(x)}{x+x} = \frac{\sin(x)}{2x}$

$\lim \limits_{(x) \to (0)} \frac{\sin(x)}{2x} = \frac{0}{0}$ Indeterminate form

Comment: You should be able to solve the limits you have there rather than saying "indeterminate form"  $\lim_\limits {x\to 0} \frac {sin x}{x} = 1, \lim_\limits {x\to 0} \frac {sin x}{2x} = \frac 12$

Comment: I feel that if you are expected to be able to do this problem, then you should be familiar with the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. L'Hopital's rule will help you here.

Comment: I can apply L'Hopital's rule but I'm unsure if my solution is generally correct. Sorry Mark just posted this as you said that. I'm not sure how to quote your comment.

Comment: @ThePointer When you're using L'Hopital's rule, just check to make sure that you can apply the theorem. Then you will have no reason to be unsure.

Comment: My question is more general. I'm curious if my solution and reasoning here (excluding the L'Hopital's aspect) is correct.

Comment: You learned how to find  $\lim_\limits {x\to 0} \frac {sin x}{x} = 1$ by the squeeze theorem, probably before you learned L'Hopital's rule.  Certainly before you learned how to find $\frac {d}{dx} sin x$

Comment: Hi Doug, Yes I know of the squeeze theorem. However, I'm curious if my reasoning to reach these two solutions was correct. I feel like I may have made a mistake along the way. If not, then that's all I wanted to know. This is my first time applying these methods so I just want to make sure that everyone else gets the indeterminate form too.

Comment: As far as your reasoning goes.  If you get different limits if you travel on different paths, then the limit does not exist.  You can disprove the existence of limits this way, but you cannot prove the existence.  To prove that a limit exists, you must show that the limit converges for all $(x,y)$ in the neighborhood.

Comment: Ok. So my calculations above are all good then? I'm using correct methodology to solve these types of limit problems?

Comment: It will work to show that a limit does not exist.  To show that it does, then you need to work a little harder.

Comment: Ok, I've had someone else look over it and they say its not the solution I'm supposed to be getting. If someone could please do as I asked in the OP and review my solution, I would greatly appreciate it. Perhaps even post your own solution for comparison so that I may see what I did incorrectly.